# IE8 and console.log - Fallback to stub if developer console isn't open

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

I currently use the following stub to help prevent console.log from throwing errors in Internet Explorer 8:

```
//  Protect against IE8 not having developer console open.
var console = window.console || {
    "log": function () {
    },
    "error": function () {
    },
    "trace": function () {
    }
};
```

I am unhappy with this solution because, when debugging against IE8, my console logs are completely removed because the developer window wasn't open initially. I need to completely reload my page with the developer window open for my console logs to not be stubbed out.

I'm hoping to come up with a more robust solution which checks for the existence of console.log upon trying to log, not on first run. This would allow me to open the IE8 developer console after starting up my program and still see errors.

Does anyone have a solution for something like that? Would a solution which does this require using a new variable for logging? e.g:

```
var newConsole = window.console || {
    "log": function () {
        if( window.console ) window.console.log(arguments);
    },
    "error": function () {
        if( window.console ) window.console.error(arguments);
    },
    "trace": function () {
        if( window.console ) window.console.trace(arguments);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

> I need to completely reload my page with the developer window open for my console logs to not be stubbed out.

Use `window.onerror` rather than a stub:

```
window.onerror = function(message, url, linenumber) {
  try
    {
    console.log([message, url, linenumber]);
    }
  catch(e)
    {
    location.hash = [message, url, linenumber];
    }
}
```

**References**

- [window.onerror](http://www.w3.org/wiki/DOM/window.onerror)
- [error | onerror event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/cc197053)
- [Diagnosing JavaScript Errors Faster with Error.stack](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2012/05/10/diagnosing-javascript-errors-faster-with-error-stack.aspx)